# "Price" and "Total" does not display in the HTML table (CS50 - Finance)

Tags: python, flask

I have been stuck on this problem set involving Flask, SQL, HTML regarding a finance website which should display a table of the user's portfolio on its homepage. [More information regarding the problem set here.](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/tracks/web/finance/)

I have been stuck on the homepage, as I manage to display a table, yet some table data does not appear. I have tried to understand why, and it does not seem that the "current share price" is the issue, as it calculates the total correctly at the bottom. I do not know where the issue arises from HTML or Flask, and if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML code (index.html):

```html
 <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
         <h2> My Portfolio </h2>
         <br>
      <tr>
        <th>Stocks Owned</th>
        <th>Shares Owned</th>
        <th>Current Price</th>
        <th>Total Value</th>
      </tr>
    {% for stock in stocks %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ stock.symbol }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock.shares }}</td>
        <td>{{ stocks.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ stocks.total }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      <tr>
        <td>CASH</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ cash }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><b>{{ grand_total }}</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is my Flask Code:

```py
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""

    stocks = db.execute("SELECT symbol, shares FROM transactions where user_id =:id", id = session["user_id"])

    updated_cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:id", id=session["user_id"])

    total_cash = float(updated_cash[0]['cash'])

    grand_total = total_cash

    for stock in stocks:
        symbol = str(stock["symbol"])
        shares = int(stock["shares"])
        quote = lookup(symbol)
        price = float(quote["price"])
        total = float(shares * price)
        grand_total = grand_total + total

    return render_template("index.html", stocks=stocks, cash=total_cash, grand_total= grand_total)
```

Here is also a picture of the table which outcomes, and the missing fields (see hyperlink):

[As you can see, the "Current Price" and "Total Value" fields are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfc0i.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot for any input thought!

Comment: Please include all `import` lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a list of dictionaries that you can iterate in Jinja with period qualified names. Right now only `stock` and `shares` from query call are the only known elements of `stocks`. Specifically, replace `for` loop with list/dictionary comprehension:

```py
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""

    stocks = db.execute("SELECT symbol, shares FROM transactions where user_id =:id", id = session["user_id"])

    updated_cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=:id", id=session["user_id"])
    total_cash = float(updated_cash[0]['cash'])

    # BUILD LIST OF DICTIONARIES
    data_list = [{'symbol': stock["symbol"],
                  'shares': stock["shares"],
                  'price': round(lookup(stock["symbol"])["price"], 2),
                  'total': round(stock["shares"] * lookup(stock["symbol"])["price"], 2)} 
                        for stock in stocks]

    # SUM ALL total ELEMENTS
    grand_total = total_cash + sum(item['total'] for item in data_list)

    return render_template("index.html", stocks=data_list, 
                           cash=total_cash, grand_total=grand_total)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, by using your code above I get error messages such as undefined variable for "symbol, shares and price" as well as "quote" being unsubscriptable

Comment: Whoops, just noticed `quote` does not derive from database and previous variables need to use dictionary keys. See edit. If quotes are maintained in database you can query once with cash.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're basically doing here is resetting your value every loop in the for stock in stocks loop. So every time you iterate over it, you're setting a new value for symbol, shares, quote, etc. What you want to do is append them to a list, and send that over.

I think something like this should work:

```
symbol = shares = quote = price = total = []

for stock in stocks:
    symbol.append(str(stock["symbol"])
    shares.append(int(stock["shares"])
    ....
```

Better yet would be to create a dictionary for each stock that holds the specific values, ensuring that all the relevant values stick together.

Something like this I guess

```
stocks = {
    "AAPL": {
        "shares": ,
        "quote": ,
        "price": ,
        "total"
    },
    "TSLA": {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to implement your code, but I keep receiving another error message now: for the price.append , sequence index is not an int, slice or index... Tanks for your help though!